# Why $\epsilon_0 = 1/(4\pi k)$ instead of $\epsilon_0 = 4\pi k$?

Tags: electrostatics, conventions, gauss-law, physical-constants

In my physics book, they consider a positive point charge $q$ and a spherical surface of radius $r$ centered on this positive charge. Then the flux through this surface is given by $$\Phi = \iint \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{A} = \iint EdA\cos\theta$$
Since $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{A}$ are parallel, $\cos\theta=1$, so the integral become just $$\iint EdA$$ Furthermore, $E$ is constant on every point so you get $$\iint EdA = E \iint dA = E(4\pi r^2)$$ where the last step follows from the fact that the surface is a sphere. Then according to Gauss's law $E=kq/r^2$ we get $$\Phi = \left(\frac{kq}{r^2}\right)(4\pi r^2) = 4\pi kq$$
Then finally they define a new constant $\epsilon_0$ which is equal to $1/(4\pi k)$ so that we get $$\iint\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{A} = \frac{q_{enclosed}}{\epsilon_0}$$
Now the real question: why is $\epsilon_0 = 1/(4\pi k)$

Why $\epsilon_0 = 1/(4\pi k)$ instead of $\epsilon_0 = 4\pi k$? Why use the inverse (reciprocal)? Whouldn't be $$\iint\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{A} = q_{enclosed} \epsilon_0$$ an "easier" and better choice?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: With easier I mean a more logical choice.

Edit 2: I was under the impression that $\epsilon_0$ is defined to make Gauss's law simpler. I voted this question to close.

Comment: How is $1/\epsilon$ *easier* than $\epsilon$? What does *easier* mean? However, as for the questions, the dielectric and magnetic constant are chosen in the SI so that the Coulomb force only presents one $k$ and their product is the inverse of the speed of light.

Comment: With easier I mean more logical. It wouldn't make sense to define a constant as the inverse of something if there is no reasons for doing it.

Comment: The main historical reasons are the ones I quoted above (this said, I still don't see how direct multiplication is more "logical" than multiplication by the 1 over the inverse).

Comment: You should wait until you learn more electrostatics. You've literally seen one place where this constant appears. One can have a lot of debates back and forth about which unit systems are best (see pi vs. tau, SI vs. cgs) but the question doesn't make sense directed at just one equation.

Comment: At this point, it's like looking at $E = mv^2/2$ and proposing we only consider twice the energy to get rid of the factor of 2.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco For example because it is more efficient for computers to do multiplication than to do division (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745819/why-is-division-more-expensive-than-multiplication). Thanks for the explanation that it is because of historical reasons. What do you mean exactly with the Coulomb force only representing one $k$?

Comment: @Kevin Why would computers have _anything_ to do with it? The theory of electromagnetism predates the invention of computers by a century. The existence of electromagnetism as a separate force predates computers by billions of years.

Comment: @knzhou Thanks, I wasn't realizing that. From the explanation in my physics book it seemed to me like they defined $\epsilon_0$ to make that equation simpler (Gauss's law).

Answer (score 3):

If we look at nature from an empirical side, we can deduce the four Maxwell equations from experiments as:
$$\nabla\vec{E}=4\pi k \rho$$
$$\nabla \times \vec{E} = - k'' \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\vec{B}$$
$$\nabla\vec{B}=0 $$
$$\nabla \times \vec{B} =4 \pi k' \vec{j} + \frac{k'}{k} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\vec{E} $$
The choice of the value of those constants $k, k', k''$ determines the unit system we use - or respectively, if we have a unit system, we will know which values to take. There are different choices that can legitimately be made, see e.g. the SI-system or cgs. All of those have different advantages or disadvantages. For a more general outline, I recommend Jackson's electrodynamics book.
The advantage of SI units, $4\pi k=1/\varepsilon_0$, $k''=1$ and $k'=k c^{-2}$, is that we can use normal units of charge etc. which we are probably used to already.
It is unfortunate that your book chooses to just motivate this by Gauss' law only ...

Comment: We do **not** deduce the *differential* form of Maxwell equations, we deduce the integral expressions and then derive their correspondence differential parts applying Stoke's theorem.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco if you feel that that makes any difference, be my guest